# Compare a value in csv file if true then fetch another value in the same file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have an input file as:

```
11722550697,TEST_003,timi-export/do/ua.10451337354/11722550697
11724290732,TEST_001,timi-import/do/ca.10451337354/11724290732
11722550697,TEST_002,timi-export/do/vo.10451337354/11722550697
11724290735,TEST_005,timi-import/do/ka.10451337354/11724290732
11722550694,TEST_006,timi-import/do/tn.10451337354/11722550697
11724290733,TEST_007,timi-export/do/kl.10451337354/11724290732
```

I will get the input from the user, and i need to compare that with the second value present in the csv file in each line (TEST_00*) and than fetch the first value, which is the id for that value for further processing.

Note:The file contains dummy data given here, and actual data varies lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need exact match, create a script, lets say `test.sh` with the following contents:

```
awk -v input="$1" -F',' '$2==input{print $1}' input_file.csv
```

Then, you can run the script as:

```
sh test.sh TEST_003
```

which will give the output as:

```
11722550697
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. how can i assign the result to a variable?

Comment: A=`awk -v input="$1" -F',' '$2==input{print $1}' test.csv` This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Using grep and cut:

```
grep '^[^,]*,'$user_input, input_file | cut -d, -f1
```

In a script you will probably use `$1` instead of `$user_input`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
cat ./script.ksh
echo "Please enter a value."
read value
awk -v val="$value" -F, '$2==val{print $1}' Input_file
```

Following will be the execution of the script.

```
./script.ksh
Please enter a value.  ##here is where user is entering value.
TEST_003
11722550697
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too now.

```
echo "Please enter a value."  ##Using echo command for printing message for user.
read value                    ##Using read command from bash to accept value from user and keep it in value.
awk -v val="$value" -F, '     ##Starting awk program here -v val to keep bash variable in it and setting field separator as comma here.
$2==val{                      ##Checking condition here if 2nd field value is equal to val here if yes then do following.
  print $1                    ##Printing first field here.
}' Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Yeah did it..  :) :)

Comment: @Vandhana, `try to make `value=$(awk -v val="$value" -F, '$2==val{print $1}' Input_file)` for keeping this in a variable too.

Comment: @Samarth What if the value is not present in the file, i have to do certain actions. I feel by checking the content of variable using if[] i can decide. Is it the correct approach?

Comment: @Vandhana, could you please do let me know if above question is dedicated to me?